# How to select a field in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have select option with jscode

Sample jscode

```
$(selector).append($("<option/>", { value: "test", text: "Test123"}));
```

The value "test" is the name of my column in table example_db

I use a stored procedure to fetch the data.

Sample query in the stored procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `sampleonly`(
in p_test varchar(50),
in Id  int()
)
BEGIN 

select p_test from example_db where Id = p_Id ; 

END
```

When I call the stored procedure, the output is the column name 'test' instead the value of columnname in 'test' which is 5413

I'm using codeigniter for framework

database example_db

```
|test|-columnname 
|5413|-data
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to construct the SQL dynamically.

```
SET @stmt = CONCAT('SELECT `', p_test, '` FROM example_db WHERE Id = ?');
PREPARE stmt FROM @stmt;
EXECUTE stmt USING p_Id;
```